# Make navbar-fixed-bottom class behave more like navbar-static-top?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

With Bootstrap3...
How can I modify the behavior of the “navbar-fixed-bottom” class, so that on long pages, I have to scroll down before I see it, but on short pages, it’s at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty standard: http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/

googling "sticking footer" brings up dozens of sites where the techniques are discussed.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading them all day. I haven't been able to get them to work however.

Comment: Have you got an example somewhere?